# Why is Orange (CSV import or Line Series) doing some weird rounding on my data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, orange, numerical

The data I have is in tab-separated format (exported from MetaTrader5):

```
<DATE>  <TIME>  <BID>   <ASK>   <LAST>  <VOLUME>    <FLAGS>
2022.09.16  15:00:00.205    0.88834 0.88857         6
2022.09.16  15:00:00.511    0.88830 0.88855         6
2022.09.16  15:00:00.939    0.88831             2
2022.09.16  15:00:01.236    0.88830             2
2022.09.16  15:00:01.566    0.88840 0.88865         6
2022.09.16  15:00:01.787    0.88838 0.88864         6
2022.09.16  15:00:02.668    0.88839 0.88863         6
2022.09.16  15:00:02.893        0.88865         4
2022.09.16  15:00:03.090    0.88838 0.88862         6
```

Anyhow as you can see the line graph of the data doesn't look right.  Everything looks rounded either to 0.888 or 0.889 but as you can see th that is losing some decimal places.

I would expect a more mountainous line graph.  If that's not natural for this data, how can I force it?

[image: Orange doing some rounding of floating point numbers]